# Calling a class method inside another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

I have service function `withFetching` that return Class `Fetch`:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as axios from 'axios';

const withFetching = url => Component => {
    class Fetch extends React.Component {
        state = {
            data: null,
            isLoading: false
        };

        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({isLoading: true});
        }

        get = (params) => {
            axios.get(url, params)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({data: response.data, isLoading: false});
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('%c ERROR', 'color: #FA12D6', error);
                });
        };

        post = data => {}

        put = () => {}

        render() {
            return <Component {...this.state}
                              {...this.props}
                              post={this.post}
                              put={this.put}
                              delete={this.delete}/>;
        }
    }

    Fetch.displayName = `Fetch(${Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component'})`;

    return Fetch;

};

export default withFetching;
```

I need call method `get` in another class. I'm doing something like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent/index';
import WithFetch from './../../../../services/withFetching';

class TableSources extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const params = {}

        WithFetch('my URL')(MyComponent).get(params)
    }

    render() {
        return (...)
    }
}

export default TableSources;
```

Comment: Are you using a Class Component as a service ? This is the same as shooting to a fly with a bazooka.
It's both easier and cleaner to store methods as functions in separate file so you can do simply MyService.get(params).then(..)

Comment: Hi! It's nice to see another approach to building a fetch service  Do you have more code to show? From what I can see, there's one thing that might not work, and that would be the get() method and the way it is called. Custom methods that aren't static may be called from parent after that component is mounted. I think you'd need refs for this, like those in React docs:[Forwarding refs from Higher-order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components)
If we're able to refine your question more, answers are possible and not just guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem of calling the CRUD service method

```
import React from 'react';
import WithFetching from './../../../../services/withFetching';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {};

    componentWillMount() {
        const {post} = this.props;
        post({data:'data'});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}

export default WithFetching('URL')(MyComponent);
```

We get the class method `post` through the `props` and call it in the lifecycle of the component (`componentWillMount`)